# Why is size of a directory different even though both of them have same contents?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, directory

I have two VM identical in terms of resources. Can someone explain to me why the below directory size is different even though both of them have same content?

**VM1**

```
root@vrni-platform:/usr/share/elasticsearch# ls -lah
total 560K
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4.0K Jul 29 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 141 root root 4.0K Jul 29 13:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jul 29 14:37 bin
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4.0K Jul 29 13:59 jdk
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jul 29 13:59 lib
drwxr-xr-x  46 root root 4.0K Jul 29 13:59 modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 523K May 28 16:35 NOTICE.txt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K May 28 16:35 plugins
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 8.0K May 28 16:35 README.asciidoc
```

**VM2**

```
root@vrni-platform:/usr/share/elasticsearch# ls -lah
total 568K
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4.0K Jul 28 13:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 141 root root 4.0K Jul 28 10:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jul 29 07:20 bin
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4.0K Jul 28 13:50 jdk
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  12K Jul 28 13:50 lib
drwxr-xr-x  46 root root 4.0K Jul 28 10:35 modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 523K May 28 16:35 NOTICE.txt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K May 28 16:35 plugins
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 8.0K May 28 16:35 README.asciidoc
```

In VM2 size of `lib` is 12K while in VM1 size of `lib` is 4K.

Content of `lib` in VM1

```
root@vrni-platform:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib# ls -lah
total 26M
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jul 29 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Jul 29 13:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12M May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-cli-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-core-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-geo-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-launchers-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.4K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-plugin-classloader-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-secure-sm-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 135K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-x-content-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112K May 28 16:35 HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M May 28 16:35 hppc-0.8.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 342K May 28 16:35 jackson-core-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58K May 28 16:35 jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  89K May 28 16:35 jackson-dataformat-smile-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  46K May 28 16:35 jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.6K May 28 16:35 java-version-checker-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 865K May 28 16:35 jna-4.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 628K May 28 16:35 joda-time-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  77K May 28 16:35 jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 780K May 28 16:35 jts-core-1.15.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 258K May 28 16:35 log4j-api-2.11.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.6M May 28 16:35 log4j-core-2.11.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7M May 28 16:35 lucene-analyzers-common-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 137K May 28 16:35 lucene-backward-codecs-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.4M May 28 16:35 lucene-core-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  89K May 28 16:35 lucene-grouping-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 205K May 28 16:35 lucene-highlighter-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 146K May 28 16:35 lucene-join-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51K May 28 16:35 lucene-memory-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  97K May 28 16:35 lucene-misc-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 372K May 28 16:35 lucene-queries-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 374K May 28 16:35 lucene-queryparser-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 219K May 28 16:35 lucene-sandbox-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 303K May 28 16:35 lucene-spatial3d-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 236K May 28 16:35 lucene-spatial-extras-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 244K May 28 16:35 lucene-suggest-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 302K May 28 16:35 snakeyaml-1.26.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 201K May 28 16:35 spatial4j-0.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51K May 28 16:35 t-digest-3.2.jar
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Jul 29 13:59 tools
```

Content of `lib` in VM2

```
root@vrni-platform:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib# ls -lah
total 26M
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  12K Jul 28 13:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Jul 28 13:50 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12M May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-cli-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-core-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-geo-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-launchers-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.4K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-plugin-classloader-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-secure-sm-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 135K May 28 16:35 elasticsearch-x-content-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112K May 28 16:35 HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M May 28 16:35 hppc-0.8.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 342K May 28 16:35 jackson-core-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58K May 28 16:35 jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  89K May 28 16:35 jackson-dataformat-smile-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  46K May 28 16:35 jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.6K May 28 16:35 java-version-checker-7.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 865K May 28 16:35 jna-4.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 628K May 28 16:35 joda-time-2.10.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  77K May 28 16:35 jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 780K May 28 16:35 jts-core-1.15.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 258K May 28 16:35 log4j-api-2.11.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.6M May 28 16:35 log4j-core-2.11.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7M May 28 16:35 lucene-analyzers-common-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 137K May 28 16:35 lucene-backward-codecs-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.4M May 28 16:35 lucene-core-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  89K May 28 16:35 lucene-grouping-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 205K May 28 16:35 lucene-highlighter-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 146K May 28 16:35 lucene-join-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51K May 28 16:35 lucene-memory-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  97K May 28 16:35 lucene-misc-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 372K May 28 16:35 lucene-queries-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 374K May 28 16:35 lucene-queryparser-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 219K May 28 16:35 lucene-sandbox-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 303K May 28 16:35 lucene-spatial3d-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 236K May 28 16:35 lucene-spatial-extras-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 244K May 28 16:35 lucene-suggest-8.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 302K May 28 16:35 snakeyaml-1.26.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 201K May 28 16:35 spatial4j-0.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51K May 28 16:35 t-digest-3.2.jar
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Jul 28 10:35 tools
```

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186813/why-does-every-directory-have-a-size-4096-bytes-4-k#:%7E:text=The%20minimum%20size%20a%20file,on%20most%20ext3%2F4%20filesystems.) the size of a directory is generally 4K in Linux containing a link to the list of the files in the directory. Then can someone let me know why is the directory size is being reported different in the above two cases?

OS - Ubuntu 16.04.6

Answer (score 1):

The space allocated to a directory grows as you add more files to it. When you remove files, the extra space is generally not reclaimed as free blocks, but kept in reserve for future use by the directory. This is similar to how a program manages its allocated memory in Unix/Linux: `malloc()` will get more memory from the kernel if needed, but `free()` won't in general return it to the kernel.

You can test this by creating first an empty directory, `touch`ing a huge number of files in it, then `rm`ing all the files. The directory will still seem to be large when you look at it with `ls -l`.